# Trigger.io build package doesn't work

Tags: trigger.io

After update my Trigger.io version and my modules, I can't package my iOS app. I don't obtain any error or warning, the console just keep on showing:

`[DEBUG] POST https://trigger.io/api/v1/app/48ba5.../build
[DEBUG] Checking API response for success or error
[DEBUG] build 46152 is working...`

And I have waited a long time, without any result. Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been a number of reports of this happening with apps that have recently updated the version of their Parse module.

Following Facebook's acquisition of Parse it is now necessary for apps that use versions of the Parse module later than 2.3 to also include the Facebook module.

If your app does not use functionality from the Facebook module you can safely set the module's `appid` configuration field to an arbitrary value.

Also see: https://trigger.io/modules/parse/current/versions/